# How to "search" with a string of values for records whose columns contain said values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Okay, I'm going to try to explain this as simply as I can.

Say I have 3 records of a certain table. We will call this table Objs, and Objs have an attribute, of type string, called colors (notice how it's plural). Here are the 3 hypothetical records in the database and their corresponding colors values:

```
obj1 colors: "red, green, blue"

obj2 colors: "blue, orange, yellow, green"

obj3 colors: "teal, purple"
```

Okay, so now say I want to be able find a subset of the records that have something in common (a good situation to use the WHERE method right?) However, I HAVE to be able to support searching for these records using either single or even ***multiple*** values. For instance:

Say my query is, `"red, green".`

Then the resulting collection of records would need to be `obj1`, and `obj2` since their color values include the keywords "red" and "green".

Say my query is, `"blue, purple".`

The resulting collection should include `obj1`, `obj2`, and `obj3`.

Also, the format of the query and the attributes of Obj will be the values delimited with a ", " since the attributes and the query itself are generated by an array. I.e., the attributes of the object and the queries themselves will always have this format:

```
"value1, value2, value3, value4"
```

It will never be like this:

```
"value1 value2 value3 value4"
```

or any other possible format.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: They have to be stored as text and not as an array?

Answer (score 0):

Let's wrap it into function,
first of all we are creating array from search string to know how many or queries we need,
then we are preparing query,
and as a final step we are passing our query and search words to our model

```
def search_function(search_string)
  names_array = search_string.split(', ')
  query = 'name LIKE ?'
  number_of_ors = names_array.count
  number_of_ors.times do 
    query += ' OR name LIKE ?'
  end
  Objects.where(query, *names_array)
end
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on Stack Overflow. In order to avoid being deleted as 'low quality', please add some explanatory text.

Comment: oh, sorry im new here

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the value, treating it as an array, against another array.  For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM example
WHERE string_to_array(colors,', ') && array['red','blue'];
```

The && operator here checks for overlaps.

Disclosure: I am an EnterpriseDB (EDB) employee.